# Can i enable Group Policy to Launch an App as an Admin?

Tags: windows, active-directory, admin, whitelist, group-policy

I want all my users to run an App as admin by default. So when the app launches, the Credentials box will not appear to enter an Admin Domain Account. so basically I would like to whitelist the app (if that's the correct terminology?)

Is there a Group Policy setting to enable a specific app to run as Admin? Or set the app up to launch as Admin?

For arguments sake, I would like to run the Notepad app as Admin for all my users so they can edit some Admin Text files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky since you don't want to expose the admin password. I've seen suggestions of using `runas /user:admin /savecred`, but once that's done, that would let the user run *anything* with `runas` under the admin credentials (if they knew how).

A better solution is described here: http://willmtz.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-force-application-to-open-in.html

In short, create a scheduled task that runs a program with specific credentials, but with no schedule. Then you create a shortcut for the user that runs the scheduled task.

This way, the user can't use the credentials to do anything other than run that one program. Depending on what you're running, you may even be able to tell it to run under the SYSTEM account, if you prefer.

You just need to configure GPO to create the scheduled task. This might help: https://www.faqforge.com/windows-server-2016/configure-scheduled-task-item-using-group-policy/

Comment: I tried this, even with the option to run whether the admin account I specified is logged in or not but it hasn't so far functioned as expected.

Comment: i open task scheduler as admin, create the task and select run as highest privilege, set the option to run if user is logged in or not then on the actions tab i select the app to open.

Comment: then on the desktop i create a shortcut to the app and nothing appears/happens.

Comment: "shortcut to the app"? It should be a shortcut to start the task.

Comment: If you created the task as an admin, you may need to let regular users see it. The tasks are saved under C:\Windows\System32\Tasks just like any other file. So as admin, give permissions for regular users to read it, just like you would a file.

Comment: yes shortcut to the task i meant sorry. i used C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN /TN “test“

Comment: So would i use C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\test in the target field of my shortcut?

Comment: No, your command seems right. But if you created it with an admin account, then other users may not be able to see the task, so you have to change the permissions on the task. You will find a file called C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\test. Make sure "Users" can read it.

Comment: Ahh. showing as access denied even though i have given my normal user account read/rw access to the task i created.

Comment: I added read/readwrite for the users onto that task in C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\test but access is denied again.

Comment: Try turning off "Run with highest privileges" on the task and see if it works that way. (I know that may not help you, but I wonder if that's what's stopping it)

Comment: ahh still no joy...the route path is authenticated for all users to r/rw to that task...

Comment: Try creating the task as a regular user in the Task Scheduler (if you can)

Comment: Cant run unfortunately. Ive tried all the ^ on a normal win10 machine that dosent connect to the domain.